# VLOOKUP across multiple worksheets in different workbook (Excel 2010)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Apologies if I placed this in the wrong place.

I am trying to create a VLOOKUP across multiple sheets in from another workbook, all the sheets have the same data and same layout, the VLOOKUP is in a separate workbook and I can get it to work on one sheet from the second workbook, but it doesn't seem to work across multiple sheets from the second workbook. 
This works for one sheet only:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,'[MAIN DATABASE 2015 - 2016.xlsm]A-C'!$B$2:$P$500,15,FALSE)
```

I have 8 sheets all with the following names A-C, D-F, G-I, J-L, M-O, P-R, S-V, W-Z.

So when I try to use all the sheets with the formula below I get #VALUE

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,'[MAIN DATABASE 2015 - 2016.xlsm]A-C:W-Z'!$B$2:$P$500,15,FALSE)
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't mind if both workbooks have to remain open to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine ranges by sheet names.

You either need to have all the data on one sheet (why split it?), or write code that (one-by-one) searches through the sheets, and combines the result(s)

Comment: Ah OK, now that makes it a bit more complicated to check everything 8 times per worksheet in another workbook. The split was made a long time so the data has been sitting like this for years.